# Google Managed Prometheus not collecting metrics from GKE cronjobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-managed-prometheus

I'm using Google's managed collection on my GKE cluster (v1.24.26) and I can't find a way to collect metrics related to Kubernetes cronjobs. I can't find kube_cronjob_next_schedule_time, kube_job_status_failed nor kube_job_status_succeeded.

Do I need to configure something specific to gather this metrics on GKE?

I tried restarting kube-state-metrics-0, restarting the collectors, nothing worked.

Comment: Google Managed services for prometheus collect Open Telemetry metrics. The mentioned metrics are Kube metrics and are natively collected by Cloud Operation services. Are you looking at the right place your metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this threw me too.

I realized (belatedly) that `kube-state-metrics` creates both a `PodMonitoring` and `ClusterPodMonitoring`.

The `PodMonitoring` resource exposes metrics published by the Pod created by `statefulset.apps/kube-state-metrics` on the Pod's `metric-self` port (8081). The `ClusterPodMonitoring` exposes metrics published on the Pod's `metric` port (8080) **but** this doesn't include `cronjob`-related metrics:

```bash
kubectl get clusterpodmonitoring/kube-state-metrics \
--output=jsonpath="{.spec.endpoints[0].metricRelabeling[0]}" \
| jq -r .
```

```
{
  "action": "keep",
  "regex": "kube_(daemonset|deployment|replicaset|pod|namespace|node|statefulset|persistentvolume|horizontalpodautoscaler|job_created)(_.+)?",
  "sourceLabels": [
      "__name__"
  ]
}
```

> **NOTE** The `regex` does **not** include `kube_cronjob` and only includes `kube_job_created` patterns.

You will need to add a regex for `kube_cronjob` and `kube_job` metrics that you want in addition.

One way (!) to do this after you've deployed Kube State Metrics, is to `kubectl patch` the `clusterpodmonitoring` resource.

Of course, a better approach is to edit the Google-provided YAML ([`kube-state-metrics.yaml#L324`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/blob/b2e0cba890beeeb1859e380c21bca2be286e0413/examples/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics.yaml#L324)) before you [Install Kube State Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/exporters/kube_state_metrics#install-exporter).

```bash
VALUE="kube_(cronjob|daemonset|deployment|job|replicaset|pod|namespace|node|statefulset|persistentvolume|horizontalpodautoscaler)(_.+)?"

PATCH="
[
    {
        'op':'replace',
        'path': '/spec/endpoints/0/metricRelabeling/0/regex',
        'value':'${VALUE}'
    }
]"

kubectl patch clusterpodmonitoring/kube-state-metrics \
--type=json \
--patch="${PATCH}"
```

**NOTE** This (`VALUE`) includes 2 changes:

- Adds **all** `kube_cronjob_*` metrics
- Adds **all** `kube_job_*` metrics (removing the redundant `kube_job_created_*` metrics)

You can demonstrate that the metrics are now scraped by Cloud Monitoring using metrics explorer and PromQL or native MQL (`prometheus.googleapis.com/kube_cronjob_next_schedule_time/gauge`) or using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/)'s [Prometheus API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/#rest-resource:-v1.projects.location.prometheus.api.v1):

```bash
PROJECT="..." # Your Project ID
ENDPOINT="https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/location/global/prometheus/api/v1/query"

TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

METRIC="kube_cronjob_next_schedule_time"

curl \
--silent \
--request POST \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--header "Accept: application/json"   \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"   \
--data "{\"query\":\"${METRIC}\"}" \
${ENDPOINT} \
| jq -r .
```

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "kube_cronjob_next_schedule_time",
          "cluster": "...",
          "cronjob": "hello",
          "instance": "kube-state-metrics-0:metrics",
          "job": "kube-state-metrics",
          "location": "...",
          "namespace": "test",
          "project_id": "..."
        },
        "value": [
          1703893639.8,
          "1703893680"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**NOTE** In this case I'd created a `CronJob` called `hello` in `test` namespace.